# Definite article vs. possessive pronoun when indicating actions

Tags: difference, definite-article, possessive-pronoun

What’s the difference between using a definite article and a possessive pronoun to indicate actions (and possibly other things, if applicable)? For example, is there any difference between using *die* and *seine* in the following sentence:

> Er sah auf seine linke Hand.

Where are the uses similar and where do they differ? Which is more common? What are the nuances of using each?

Answer (score 3):

Really necessary is the possessive pronoun only, when other persons are on the scene for disambiguation - whose hand did he look at. (Dolls etc. could also qualify.) But there is no harm using it in the other cases too, actually I consider this as more naturally.